# Data Modeling tool Powerdesigner Supported Database

Tags: data-modeling, netezza, powerdesigner

Is the Netezza database supported by Powerdesigner v15? Where can one find the list of database supported by Powerdesigner?

Comment: There was Netezza 4.5 support in PowerDesigner 15.3.

Comment: And a later PowerDesigner 16.6 SP02 has a DBMS definition for Netezza 7.

Comment: look for  .xdb or .xem files on github.com, or similar sites. These may contain database definition files written by expert users

Answer (score 0):

In PowerDesigner 15 only Netezza 4.5 was supported.

I can only give you a list of supported DMBS in PowerDesigner 16:

[DBMS List PowerDesigner 16 Part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZo3B.png)

[DBMS List PowerDesigner 16 Part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmlPv.png)

[DBMS List PowerDesigner 16 Part3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWo7s.png)

In this version the Netezza 5.0 and 7.x are supported.